# Using python to open various links

Tags: python

This is my first post here and i hope i get my answers.
I want to open various links from my ftp server, and do some stuff in them. My links are http://mypage/photos0001/ , /photos002/, /photos003/ etc.
How can i write a script to open all of them and do the same job in all of them?
I tried:
Link = 'http://mypage/photos0001/' + 1
To do something like loop, but this doesn't work of course.
Any help?

Comment: You just want to open those links or do you want to do something else also

Comment: Could you please show us the code which you tried?

Comment: Inside those folders there are some files (.jpg images actiually). /photos0001/img001.jpg, img002.jpg atc. I want to open ALL folders and download my files but i dont know how to do it automatically....i have to try one by one path1='http://mypage/photos0001/' , path2='xxxxx/photos0002' and so on.

Comment: I want a script to open first folder, do what i want to do in that folder, and loop back but add + '1' to folder name each time. so that on second loop it will open folder photos0002

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see your actual FTP directory tree, this may be a little difficult, but hopefully the following can get you started.

Consider reading up on `ftplib` for more information (see [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ftplib.html))

```
import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP('mypage')
ftp.login()

for dir in ftp.nlst():
    if 'photos' in dir:
        ftp.cwd('/mypage/{}'.format(dir))
        for file in ftp.nlst():
            if file.endswith('.jpg'):
                try:
                    print('Attempting to download {}...'.format(file), end=' ')
                    with open(file, 'wb') as f:
                        ftp.retbinary('RETR ' + file, f.write, 8*1024)
                    print('[SUCCESS]')
                except Exception as e:
                    print('[FAILED]')
                    print(e)

ftp.close()
```

So let's try and run through what is going on here:

1. Log in to your FTP server `mypage`.
2. List all the directories found in the root directory of your server.
3. If the folder name contains 'photos' then change working directory into that folder.
4. List all the files in this photos sub-folder.
5. If the file ends in `.jpg` its probably a picture we want.
6. Create a file on your system with the same name, and download the picture into it.
7. Repeat.

Now, expect to run into problems when you directory tree turns out to be slightly different than you've described to use here; however, you should be able to modify the example to fit your server. I do know this code works, as I have been able to use it to recursively download `.html` files from `ftp.debian.org`.